# DevExpress: Group items by some property in ComboBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, combobox, devexpress

I have a `DevExpress` element in my project - `GridView`. And there's a ComboBox column. 
It has a DataSource property assigned to a collection of some items. So I need to group these items by a specific field.

It should look like this:

```
Group 1
  - item 1
  - item 2
  - item 3
Group 2
  - item 4
  - item 5
```

Could you help me how can I implement this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution in this link about what you asked for, you just need to modify it a bit for using in a grid: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q303283

Comment: No, it's not what I actually need. I need to make groups right in combobox, with headers - I've updated the question

Comment: This is exactly what you asked for: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q303283

Comment: I modified my answer.